# New VSCode extension can't find vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

Why does a new VSCode extension created with yeoman generator immediately not find vscode when starting debug?

Clean install of node, yeoman, and generator "code".

While I can continue to debug with this error, why isn't vscode found? Is it extraneous if debugging actually works?

Answer (score 0):

Type Ctrl+` to get the console and then `npm i` whereupon you will get a message similar to this

> Detected VS Code engine version: ^1.31.0 Found minimal version that
>   qualifies engine range: 1.31.0 Fetching vscode.d.ts from:
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/vscode/7c66f58312b48ed8ca4e387ebd9ffe9605332caa/src/vs/vscode.d.ts
>   vscode.d.ts successfully installed!

After that things should be hunky dory.